laravel ui auth login перенаправляет на другую страницу после входа и обратно
Мой проект лежит на гитхабе.
Я его скачиваю на другую машину.
Выполняю composer install, проект дополнен необходимыми файлами, запускаю php artisan serve.
На странице /login после входа (испльзуется стандартный auth/ui) должен перенаправлять на /home, но после перенаправления, судя по Inspect из хрома, он снова возвращается на страницу /login. Вот скрин

Идет login 302, home 302 и возврат на login с 200. В чем может быть дело?
При каждом обновлении страницы обновляется и сессия, может в этом дело. В настройках стоит время сессии 120, сессия использует файловую систему.
Версия Laravel 10.29

laravel ui/auth использует модель User. В ней по умолчанию основной ключ это поле 'id' и оно является автоинкрементирующимся.
Проблема появилась из-за того, что моя таблица не использует 'id' поле с автоинкрементом. Вместо этого поля уникальным идентификатором кортежа является поле 'login' и оно, естественно, не является автоинкрементирующимся.
В модели User необходимо это указать:
protected $primaryKey = 'login';
public $incrementing = false;

Поле 'incrementing' должно быть public.
Вопрос закрыт.
